# Dynamically set layout_below doesn't take effect

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a checkbox with `layout_below` one view. Then when that view's visibility is set to gone, I'm trying to set the checkbox to below another one. I can't get it work, my code is below, any tip? thanks

```
if (certificate.getType() == VerifiedCertificate.STUDENT_CARD) {
            anchorSchoolView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgSchool.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtSchool.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtSchoolName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) cbQuestion.getLayoutParams();
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.txtSchoolName);
            cbQuestion.setLayoutParams(lp);

        } else {
            anchorSchoolView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imgSchool.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtSchool.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtSchoolName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) cbQuestion.getLayoutParams();
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.txtDocType);
            cbQuestion.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
```

**Update:** XML file as requested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOtherSide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/view_other_side" />

    <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDocType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/doc_id_card"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:textStyle="normal"
        app:textWeight="light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDocFile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDocType"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img_id_card" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconDoc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgDocFile"

        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_credit_card" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchorDoc"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iconDoc"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconDoc"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/anchorDoc"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/anchorDoc"
        android:text="@string/document_id_number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDocNumberValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/anchorDoc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anchorDoc"
        android:text="0123456" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iconDoc"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchorDate"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iconDate"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconDate"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRegoDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/anchorDate"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/anchorDate"
        android:text="@string/rego_day" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRegoValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/anchorDate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anchorDate"
        android:text="01/06/2010" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconSchool"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDocNumberValue"

        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_school" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchorSchool"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iconSchool"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconSchool"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSchool"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/anchorSchool"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/anchorSchool"
        android:text="@string/school_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSchoolName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/anchorSchool"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anchorSchool"
        android:text="School name" />

    <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbSecondQuesion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtSchoolName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/confirm_doc_is_genuine"
        app:textStyle="normal"
        app:textWeight="medium" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update 2:** It does work, I just set to the wrong view id

Comment: post you xml code snippet please

Comment: @Aakash just update my question, cheers :)

Comment: In your question what is another one? -> I'm trying to set the checkbox to below another one

Comment: ah, awesome question, I set to the wrong `another one`, should be `txtDocNumberValue`. Thanks heaps

Comment: didn't give a chance to answer ;) by the way its cool that my question helped